# Unable to import pages and numbers documents with UIDocumentPicker

Tags: objective-c, file, ios8, file-import, uidocumentpickervc

I'm developing an app that provides the ability to store cloud documents. 
This app will have the option to import data from other apps using the new `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. 
Everything works fine and I'm able to show the picker view controller. 
This is the code that I'm using to import the file:

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {



if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeImport) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

         NSString*  path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MyHandyTap/%@/%@",documentsDirectory,self.cartella,[url lastPathComponent]];

        BOOL startAccessingWorked = [url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
        NSURL *ubiquityURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

        __block NSData *data;

        NSFileCoordinator *fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] init];
        NSError *error;
        [fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:url options:0 error:&error byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {

            data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:newURL];

            [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

        }];
        [url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];

    }
}
```

With this code I'm able to import a lot of different file formats (.pdf, .txt, .rtf, .doc etc) however if I try to import files .pages or .numbers files from iCloud the call to `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:newURL]` returns `null`.

Is it possibile to let users import these kinds of files?

I've red the documentation listed here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH18-SW2 
and I've downloaded the example listed here : https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2014/wwdc_2014_sample_code/newboxanintroductiontoiclouddocumentenhancementsinios8.0.zip
however I'm not able to figure out how to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance for your help

Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even I did not test it, but likely you get the problems, because documents of type .pages or .numbers are no single files, but bundles. So you cannot read them with `-dataWithContentsOfURL:`.

Did you check copying with [`-copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:) (`NSFileManager`)?

Comment: Hi your answer pointed me to the right solution. I was trying to upload .pages and .numbers to a web server (in order to store them in a personal cloud). However, because those are not simple files but bundles I was having a lot of problems. Zipping them before the upload and unzipping them after the download solved my problems.

Comment: Of course that is another way to handle the "bundle problem".

Comment: Can you help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613645/add-edit-in-exel-or-edit-photo-extension